# I want to know if someone replied to me and send a message to them

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am writing a Discord bot. I want it to reply to the user only when they reply to my bot.

This is the relevant code:

```
if message.reference:
    if "How are" in message.content.lower():
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(list4), reference=message)
```

The problem is that the message is sent even if a user replies to someone else, rather than to the bot. How can I make sure that a message is only sent when the user replies to the bot specifically?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently just checking if the message has a reference, i.e., if it's a reply to another, not if it's replied to anyone *specifically*.

To check if a user has replied to one of your messages, use [`message_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.MessageReference.message_id) to get the message the user replied to. You can then [check if the message was sent by your bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.user) by getting the (referred) `Message` and then checking its [`author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.author):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    referred_message = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.reference.message_id) #Get the message to which it's a reply
    if referred_message.author == bot.user: #Check if the message it replies to was sent by your bot
        if "how are" in message.content.lower(): #Changed "How are" to "how are" (small H)
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            await message.channel.send(random.choice(list4), reference=message)
```

Also, `if "How are" in message.content.lower():` will always return `False`, as even (what you're expecting) "How are <something>" when `.lower()`ed will not ***exactly*** match "***H***ow are <something>" (`"H" != "h"`), so I've changed it to "how are" so it works properly.